# Adding to vector after indexing from it

Tags: rust

I'm curious about this example here https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-01-vectors.html

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling collections v0.1.0 (file:///projects/collections)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
4 |     let first = &v[0];
  |                  - immutable borrow occurs here
5 | 
6 |     v.push(6);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
7 | 
8 |     println!("The first element is: {}", first);
  |                                          ----- immutable borrow later used here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `collections`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

At a high level, how is a reference to an item in `v` the same as a reference to `v` itself. Syntactically how is this enforced? *How would something with an example type be trivially implemented to exemplify this?* All I could find so far was that ownership prevents this, but I can't find anything explaining it under the hood.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the vector needs to be resized to accommodate the additional item, it will have to allocate new memory and move all the existing items into that new allocation. This would break the outstanding reference, which is why it's not allowed. Other forms of mutation could similarly break references - e.g. deleting an item could either delete the item being referenced or cause it to be moved within the vector.

This is enforced by the way lifetimes and references work in Rust. `Vec`s implement the [`Index` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Index.html#tymethod.index) to provide the `[]` operator, which has a method signature of `fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output`. Notice how `self` is taken by immutable reference (`&`) and the function also returns an immutable reference. Since lifetimes aren't explicitly specified for these references, the compiler infers that they are linked - i.e., the returned reference is only valid as long as a reference to the container itself would be.

Next, you try to mutate the vector, using [`push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push). This has the signature `fn push(&mut self, value: T)`. Note that this function takes `self` by *mutable* reference (`&mut`) which requires that there are no other references to the vector. Since the compiler figured out in the previous step that indexing a vector returns a reference that is tied to the vector itself, it doesn't allow us to call `push`.

You can create a similar example very easily with code like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    a: i32
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn get_a(&self) -> &i32 {
        &self.a
    }
    
    fn set_a(&mut self, value: i32) {
        self.a = value;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut thing = MyStruct { a: 5 };
    let reference = thing.get_a();
    thing.set_a(10); // error! thing is already borrowed due to get_a()
    println!("Value: {}", reference);
}
```

The Rust book goes into these topics in a few places. I'd recommend reading through [References and Borrows](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#references-and-borrowing) as well as [Validating references with lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#validating-references-with-lifetimes).

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer twice, ty!! The big part I was missing was &someInstance.someField is really borrowing the instance as well, not just the field